# pandas pivot table aggregating over 2 diff columns and 2 functions: sum and mean

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have data of the form

```
    Date_Time           LF      Name        Count   pwr     TS
0   2022-08-03 00:00:02 2885184100  OpenP1  1   0.302229    1
1   2022-08-03 00:00:02 2885184100  Net3    1   4.790000    3
2   2022-08-03 00:00:02 2885184100  OpenP1  1   0.000000    1
3   2022-08-03 00:00:02 2885184100  OpenP1  3   1.300000    4
4   2022-08-03 00:00:02 2885184100  Net3    1   0.033000    4
5   2022-08-03 00:00:05 2885184220  OpenP1  1   0.302229    1
6   2022-08-03 00:00:05 2885184220  Net3    1   4.790000    3
7   2022-08-03 00:00:05 2885184220  OpenP1  1   0.520000    1
8   2022-08-03 00:00:05 2885184220  OpenP1  2   0.000000    4
9   2022-08-03 00:00:05 2885184220  Net3    1   0.440000    4
```

And I need to aggregate in the following way:

For each LF, I want to:

1. SUM the `pwr` field for all the same values of `TS` AND `Name` then
2. AVERAGE across the (up to 4) TS *for each* `Name`. That final mean would be associated with LF.

So for LF = 2885184100 we have
OpenP1 0.302229 1
OpenP1 0.000000 1

OpenP1 1.300000 4

TS 1 total = 0.302229
TS 4 total = 1.3

So the average for LF = 2885184100 and OpenP2 is 0.801115
I need to do the same for Net3 at LF = 2885184100 and then repeat for each LF...

I also want to sum `Count` for each LF -- that should be straightfoward:

```
    Date_Time           LF          OpenP1_pwr  Net3_pwr    OpenP1_cnt  Net3_cnt
0   2022-08-03 00:00:02 2885184100  0.801115    1.205750    5   2
1   2022-08-03 00:00:05 288518220   0.205557    2.615000    4   2
```

I thought I could figure out a pivot table for this... but I can't get it right.

I thought something like this was close:

```
tmp=theData.pivot_table(index='LF', columns=['Name','TS'], values=['pwr', 'Count'],
                      aggfunc={'pwr': '??','Count':'sum'},
                      fill_value=0)
```

but them I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you explain why OpenP1_pwr is 0.987229 when LF is 2885184100?

Comment: @earnric show step by step how you get one of the values (I don't understand the logic).

Comment: How do you get `Net3_pwr` value for `OpenP1` observation?

Comment: @MarcinKamil sorry... i didn't do the math correctly.

Comment: @earnic I edited my answer but general formula is the same.

Comment: @earnric df.groupby(['LF', 'Name'])['pwr'].agg(['sum', 'count', 'mean']).reset_index()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your output table reflects what you describe.

1. I would drop "Name" column from the output because it makes no sense: what does 'Net3_pwr' value mean in the first row?
2. The average value for LF = 2885184100 and OpenP1 is not 0.801115. There are 3 observations (0.0 counts as one too), so the sum divided by 3 equals 0.534076.
3. You mention averaging the sum of 'pwr' across 'TS' but that doesn't show anywhere in the output.

Here's what I think you are looking for:

```
data = data.pivot_table(index=['Date_Time', 'LF'], columns=['Name'], values=['pwr', 'Count'], aggfunc={'pwr':'mean', 'Count':'sum'})
data = data.set_axis(csv.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Output:

```
                                   Count_Net3  Count_OpenP1  pwr_Net3  pwr_OpenP1
Date_Time              LF
   2022-08-03 00:00:02 2885184100           2             5    2.4115    0.534076
   2022-08-03 00:00:05 2885184220           2             4    2.6150    0.274076
```

First line will find mean for 'pwr' and sum the 'Count' for each 'Name' grouped by 'LF'.
Second part flattens multiindex from first line.

Comment: As you note, to get 'pwr_Net3' you have to sum everywhere you have Name = Net3 and TS = x, where x is element of {1,2,3,4} ... Then you average across those sums. 
And yes: you really don't have 'Name' in the output... I made a mistake keeping it in there. Thanks for this solution! I'll test it later tonight

Comment: however, I don't think it'll work just doing "mean" for the pwr column aggregated by Name ... it always has to be the average of the 4 timeslots (x elem {1,2,3,4}).

Comment: Ok you're solution gave it to me... I just need to make one change:
aggfunc={'pwr':sumdiv,...} where I lambda x: x.sum() / 4